# Get Unix time from TextView

Tags: java, simpledateformat, unix-timestamp

I have TextView with time: **HH:mm:ss:ms**
For example I have time: 00:20:03:19. My function returns **-9596**
How to convert this time to unix time? where is the mistake? Thanks.

```
 private long convertStringToUnixTime() throws ParseException {
    String dateStr = "00:20:03:19";
    long unixTime;

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:ms");
    unixTime = formatter.parse(dateStr).getTime();

    unixTime = unixTime / 1000;

    return unixTime;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This returns `22803019` - which is the milliseconds since epoch.

```
new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS").parse("00:20:03:19").getTime()
```

You didn't say whether you wanted seconds or milliseconds, but since you are parsing milliseconds, I guess you want the later, so no need to divide.

All in all, your method could be much shorter if you give the String as the parameter

```
private long convertStringToUnixTime(String dateStr) throws ParseException {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss:SSS").parse(dateStr).getTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Milliseconds is 'S'. And It is three. Your format should be as "HH:mm:ss:SSS".

More information here: [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)